# In Junit, how to prevent from printing expected exception which is thrown intentionally and caught already in log?

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j, logback

I guess this is a junit and Logback problem. In my project, Logging is done through slf4j. The logging implementation is Logback.

So I have a class:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class A {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final String DEFAULT_REPLY = "just continue...";

    public String doSomething(Object value) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.methodAbc(value);
        } catch (JPException e) {
            log.error("Exception while processing value", e);
            return DEFAULT_REPLY;
        }
    }
}
```

and its test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {
    @Before
    public void init() {
        processor = new A();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mockMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
        JP mockJp = mock(JP.class);
        Exception thrownException = new JPException(mockJp, null);

        when(mockMapper.methodAbc(any())).thenThrow(thrownException);

        String result = processor.doSomething("abc");

        assertTrue(result.equals("just continue..."));
    }
}
```

I don't have any problem with the test itself. Just as you can see, in the test, the `JPException` will be printing out on the log, because it's intentionally thrown.

When I debug through logs, there're too many this kind of expected exceptions, I'm just wondering is there a way to remove them from logs? And of course still print other exceptions which is not expected.

Comment: what are you using as logging impl ?

Comment: @davidxxx, we're using Logback.

Answer (score 1):

Logback has the functionality to support filters and evaluations based on certain logic.

This link is probably what you could be looking for :

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#Evaluators

You can configure your logback to do or not do certain action if it is an instance of any exceptio - in your case `JPException`

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's very useful and I will read it through. The problem is this kind of Exceptions are in different types, like `IOException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `JPException` and so on. I have a feeling if `filters` and `Evaluators` are the way to go, there will be a very large logback.xml file there. Is there a way from the junit side, like when we intentionally throw an exception using `thenThrow`, something can be done on the logback side?

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but does the annotation `@Test (expected =JPException.class)`  on your method in the JUnit, give what you are looking for? In this case, when the exception was not thrown you'll get the following error `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected Exception.....JPException`.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case, because the exception is caught outside the test method so to the test, there's no JPException thrown. But it works with those exceptions throws inside the test method. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be of any more help. That's as far as I know on this subject. I have used logback functionality for this but not for too many exceptions like you want to, and I can see why the logback might get 'long' in your case. I would just route these Junit exceptions to another log file altogether, for starters, but I am curious about how this could be resolved as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Create a mock for the log.
2. Inject the mock into the class being tested.
3. Assert that the error method on the mocked log object was called.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit. To make the question more clear, I don't have any problem to test anything. the test itself is okay. Just I don't want to see the expected exception `JPException` to be printed out on the log.

Comment: performing steps 1 and 2 above will prevent the logging of the exception in the log file.